# ¿PORQUE ME MANDA ESTO? SQLQueryRow($sql); echo

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo este proyecto en la laptop de mi trabajo. Corre bien y todo, pero cuando llevo este proyecto a mi labtop personal para avanzar me manda esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esos mensajes `SQL` el menú no carga ya modifique el archivo de conexión según mi DB, pero aun así pasa esto.

```
<?php 

//mthinnows
class Class_BD{

    var $usuario ='MI_USUARIO';
    var $password = 'MI_CONTRASEÑA';
    var $servidor = 'localhost';
    var $base = 'MI_BD';



    public $links;

    function __construct(){
        $this->links = mysqli_connect($this->servidor, $this->usuario, $this->password, $this->base);
    } 

    function SQLQueryRS($sql) //Metodo para devolver un set de registros
    {
        $resultado = mysqli_query($this->links,$sql);
        return $resultado;
    }

    function SQLQueryRow($sql) //Metodo para devolver un set de registros
    {
        $rs = mysqli_query($this->links,$sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs);
        return $row;
    }

    function SQLCommand($sql) //Metodo para ejecutar una consulta directa sin retorno
    {       
        if(mysqli_query($this->links,$sql) === TRUE){
            return TRUE;
        }else{
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    function SQLMaxId($tabla, $Id) //Metodo para devolver el ultimo Id insertado
    {
        $row = $this->SQLQueryRow("select Max($Id) as n from $tabla");
        return $row["n"];
    }

    function SQLClose(){
        $cerrar = mysqli_close($this->links);
        return $cerrar;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Enseña el código bro, o bien enseña bien el error, lo que dice

Comment: SQLQueryRow($sql); echo eso es lo que sale los errores, y el codigo de conexion es:

Comment: ya puse mi codigo de conexion

Comment: Bro, hay una función para poner ordenadamente tu código... Pero a ver qué pedo

Comment: ¿Te paso una forma de conexión con PDO bien? Creo que te serviría, es un objeto que instancias

Comment: el detalle que si funciona en la lap de mi trabajo pero en mi lap personal no

Comment: Creo que ya vi. Si todo está en una línea como lo envíaste, comentaste a partir de function SQLQueryRS($sql) // Y pues así ya no aplica nada, estaba ordenando tu código cuándo vi eso XD

Comment: si sale ese SQLQueryRS($sql) y no se porque

Comment: Me refiero al comentario //

Comment: '//' es para aplicar comentarios, inutiliza todo lo que esté dentro de un comentario

Comment: Y tenías corchetes demás

Comment: Te envíe lo que creo serviría. Aunque te aconsejo usar PDO, es más facil y bonito UwU

Comment: @JosuePalma, te recomiendo revisar tu configuración [`short_open_tag`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
links = mysqli_connect($this->servidor, $this->usuario, $this->password, $this->base);
function SQLQueryRS($sql) { $resultado = mysqli_query($this->links,$sql); return $resultado; } 
function SQLQueryRow($sql) { $rs = mysqli_query($this->links,$sql); $row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs); return $row; } 
function SQLCommand($sql) { if(mysqli_query($this->links,$sql) === TRUE){ return TRUE; }else{ return FALSE; } } 
function SQLMaxId($tabla, $Id) { $row = $this->SQLQueryRow("select Max($Id) as n from $tabla"); return $row["n"]; } 
function SQLClose(){ $cerrar = mysqli_close($this->links); return $cerrar; }
?>
```

... Mmm Para ser franco contigo, nunca entendí bien el mysqli Jajajajaja, trata con PDO

```
<?php

    class Conexion {
        private $tipo_de_base = 'mysql';
        private $nombre_de_base = 'estacionamiento';
        private $host = 'localhost';
        private $usuario = 'root';
        private $contrasena = ''; 
        protected $conexion;
        protected $statement;

        public function __construct($prueba = 0) { // PHP 5 permite a los desarrolladores declarar métodos constructores para las clases
            try {
                $this->conexion = new PDO("{$this->tipo_de_base}:dbname={$this->nombre_de_base};host={$this->host};charset=utf8", $this->usuario, $this->contrasena);
                if ($prueba == 1) {
                    echo 'Se ha conectado a la base de datos exitosamente';
                }
            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                return false;//echo 'Ha surgido un error y no se puede conectar a la base de datos. Detalle: ' . $e->getMessage();
                exit;
                die();

            }
        } 

        public function __destruct() { // PHP 5 introduce un concepto de destructor similar al de otros lenguajes orientados a objetos
            if ($this->conexion !== null) { $this->conexion = null; }
            if ($this->statement !== null) { $this->statement = null; }
        }

        public function query(String $query) {
            $this->statement = $this->conexion->prepare($query); // Prepara una sentencia para su ejecución y devuelve un objeto sentencia
        }

        public function bind(String $param, $value, $type = null) {
            if(is_null($type)) {
                switch (true) {
                    case is_int($value):
                        $type = PDO::PARAM_INT; // Representa el tipo de dato INTEGER de SQL .
                        break;

                    case is_bool($value):
                        $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL; // Representa un tipo de dato booleano.
                        break;

                    case is_null($value):
                        $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL; // Representa el tipo de dato NULL de SQL.
                        break;

                    default:
                        $type = PDO::PARAM_STR; // Representa el tipo de dato CHAR, VARCHAR de SQL, u otro tipo de datos de cadena.
                        break;
                }
            }
            $this->statement->bindValue($param, $value, $type); // Vincula un valor a un parámetro
        }

        public function execute() {
            $this->statement->execute(); // Ejecuta una sentencia preparada
        }

        public function next() {
            $this->statement->nextRowset(); // Avanza hasta el siguiente conjunto de filas de un gestor de sentencia multiconjunto de filas
        }

        public function close() {
            $this->statement->closeCursor(); // Cierra un cursor, habilitando a la sentencia para que sea ejecutada otra vez
        }

        public function lastInsert() {
            return $this->conexion->lastInsertId(); // Devuelve el ID de la última fila o secuencia insertada
        }

        public function single() {
            $this->execute();
            return $this->statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); //Obtiene la siguiente fila de un conjunto de resultados
            // PDO::FETCH_ASSOC: devuelve un array indexado por los nombres de las columnas del conjunto de resultados.
        }

        public function resultset() {
            $this->execute();
            return $this->statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // Devuelve un array que contiene todas las filas del conjunto de resultados
            // PDO::FETCH_ASSOC: devuelve un array indexado por los nombres de las columnas del conjunto de resultados.
        }

        public function column() {
            $this->execute();
            return $this->statement->fetchColumn(); // Devuelve una única columna de la siguiente fila de un conjunto de resultados
        }

        public function count() {
            $this->execute();
            return $this->statement->rowCount(); // Devuelve el número de filas afectadas por la última sentencia SQL
        }
    }

?>
```

La que te envíe es la que yo uso, hay mejores, pero esa me gusta a mi, ¿como usarla?

```
$c = new Conexion;
```

Para conectar

```
Ya después haces $c->query()
```

Y así con todo, con lo de Max Id, solo haz

```
$c = new Conexion;
$c->query("select Max($Id) as n from $tabla");
$resultado = $c->column();
```

Y suerte supongo

Comment: ya lo puse asi y sigue ese mismo problema :(

Comment: que sad men :´v

Comment: seguire intentando xdd

Comment: gracias igual de todas formas